# I don't understand this sentence 「自分は深く考えてなかった」

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm lost, I think I get the general gist of the statement, but I'm unsure as to what the whole meaning is and while there's a few grammar points I'm unsure of (「とか」 and 「なんだな」 I'm guessing are a listing particle and a shortened version of 「なのだな」) I can't make sense of the **「自分は深く考えてなかった」** part.

(It's a comment on one of my HelloTalk posts. Basically me saying I think we learn a lot from your own and others' mistakes)

The post:

> 私もそうおもいます ここは間違いやすいとこなんだな、とか自分は深く考えてなかったけどこういう理屈なんだな、とか。

What I think they said:

> I think so too. Here's somewhere you can easily make mistakes isn't or
>   [This is the part I'm a little confused about] but, ["this is the
>   reason"?]

Comment: So they said 「深く[教]{おし}えてなかった」, not 「深く[考]{かんが}えてなかった」...?

Comment: Yes I feel this sentence doesn't fit the context well if it were 教えて instead of 考えて. If this 理屈 is something you've just learned, you won't say "although I haven't taught it" as if you have known it since long before.

Comment: Ah, it seems i have in fact misread it. I fee like an idiot now. it was 「考えて」, sorry!
Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: あら・・ じゃ、とりあえず編集しておきますね・・ ＾＾ Nevermind, let me edit your post accordingly ＾＾

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. 「〜とか」 is a listing particle for general examples of the topic being discussed. However It should always come after the example being given. You can see the writer used it at the beginning of the second sentence when he should have used 「たとえば」instead. *(which means "for example") Also it seems like an afterthought at the end of his final sentence too so it doesn't necessarily need to be there either.

Ok so let's break down the part your confused about.
自分{じぶん}は 深く{ふかく}教えてなかった{おしえてなかった}
I'm guessing the first part that might be confusing is 深く{ふかく}. This is the adverb form for the adjective 深い{ふかい}(deep; profound). You can make any い-adj into an adverb by dropping the い and replacing it with く. You can also do this with な-adj but instead you add に to the end. eg: 静か{しずか}(quiet) --> 静か{しずか}に(quietly)
Therefore 深く{ふかく} would mean "deeply" or "profoundly"

The second part I'll address is the verb they used.
教える{おしえる} means "to teach; to instruct". Here they expressed in the past continuous state. The 〜ている form it means it's continuous and he used 「〜て(い)なかった」 which means was not x-ing. However he dropped the い after て which is how you might casually speak the words. It still means the same thing just is a more colloquial way of conjugating the verb ending.

So in conclusion,
「とか」things like~ (*for example)
「自分{じぶん}は」as for myself
「深く{ふかく}」deeply
「教えてなかった{おしえてなかった}」was not teaching
「とか、自分{じぶん}は深く{ふかく}教えてなかった{おしえてなかった}けど…」

If we put it together it sounds like "For example, as for myself was not deeply teaching but..."

This still sounds a little confusing though so based on the conversation topic I would conclude the writer wanted to say "For example, as for myself I have not been extensively taught but..."
To do this they would have needed to use the passive form of 教える{おしえる} which would be 「教えられなかった{おしえられなかった}」.
Also as a side note the writer seems to write as they think which might explain why their sentence structure is the way it is.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand it much better now. This really helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: `I have not been extensively taught`<- 教えてなかった is active voice. It cannot mean passive "have not been taught". "I have not been extensively taught" should be 「深く教え**られ**てなかった」.